# angular data is not displaying properly with phantomjs

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, phantomjs, yii2

am new to angular js & phantomjs,  am working in website with angular...i need to create download of that page, so am using phantomjs for this...

**on click of download button, am calling js function**

```
var downUrl = "index.php?r=route/download";
$.ajax({
        method:'POST',
        data: {id: <?php echo Yii::$app->request->get('id'); ?> ,             url:"<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>"},
        url: downUrl,
}).done(function(data) {
var response=$(data);
var phantomPath = response.filter('#phanton_temp_file').val();
console.log(phantomPath);
if(phantomPath){
    window.top.location.href = phantomPath;
 }
});
```

**in controller function**

```
$fileName   = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));  
$pdfUrl = \Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl."/phantomjs/create.php?filename=".$fileName.".png&url=http://example.com/frontend/web/index.php?r=route/detail&id=427";    
echo "<input type='hidden' value='".$pdfUrl."' name='phanton_temp_file' id='phanton_temp_file' />";
```

**create php page is**

```
 <?php
 $name = time()."-".$_REQUEST['filename'];
 $tempFile = "../../temp/".$name;
 sleep(60);
 $result = shell_exec('phantomjs rasterize.js '.$_REQUEST['url'].' '.$tempFile);
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$name);
header('Content-type: application/png');
readfile($tempFile);
?>
```

**js file is**

```
 var page = require('webpage').create(),
 system = require('system'),
  address, output, size;
 if (system.args.length < 3 || system.args.length > 5) {
  console.log('Usage: rasterize.js URL                             filename[paperwidth*paperheight|paperformat] [zoom]');
  console.log('  paper (pdf output) examples: "5in*7.5in", "10cm*20cm", "A4", "Letter"');
   phantom.exit(1);
 } else {
 address = system.args[1];
 output = system.args[2];
 page.viewportSize = {width: 1380, height: 1024};
 if (system.args.length > 3 && system.args[2].substr(-4) === ".png") {
    size = system.args[3].split('*');
    page.paperSize = size.length === 2 ? { width: size[0], height: size[1], margin: '0px' }
    : { format: system.args[3], orientation: 'portrait', margin: '1cm' };
    }
    if (system.args.length > 4) {
      page.zoomFactor = system.args[4];
    }
    page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(output);
            page.render(output);
            phantom.exit();
        }, 2000);
      }
     });
     }
```

am  getting screenshot like below, angular data is not rendering...i tried with  time delay also..but still giving same screenshot...pls help me...thanks in advance

//-------------------------------------------

in my angular controller, i used below code also

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
   $scope.htmlReady();
 });
```

[image]

Comment: Please highlight your codes properly.

Comment: Please register to the [`onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html), [`onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html), [`onResourceError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html), [`onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events in the rasterize script. Maybe there are errors.

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem

i had used the CDN but instead use the angularjs library that is available for download

and include in your page

happy coding

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS 2.2.1 not supported some angular.js defines. ex. const.
Therefore you can't render angular.js.

You can use old angular.js version.

I tried not stable PhantomJS 2.5 version. It is rendering but it is not stable and you can get another errors.